# How to set selection after Transforms.insertNodes() in Slate JS

Tags: slatejs

I am trying to add a new line right below current selection, then put the selection to the new line.

```
let current_path = props.selection.anchor.path[0]
Transforms.insertNodes(editor, {type:'line', children:[{ text:'' }]},{at: [current_path+1]});
const point = { anchor: { path: [current_path+1, 0], offset: 0 }, focus: { path: [current_path+1, 0], offset: 0 }}
// set focus
ReactEditor.focus(editor);
// set selection
Transforms.select(editor, point);
```

But this came up with an error: Error: Cannot resolve a DOM node from Slate node: {"text":""}. Does anyone know how to solve it or have other way to realize it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I stumble into the problem and found the answer. You'll need to save the `selection`, then use `Transform.select` to restore it.

For example

```js
import { Transforms } from "slate";


// clone to store selection
const previousSelection = Object.assign({}, editor.selection);

// restore selection
Transform.select(editor, previousSelection)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to look at parent to increment position and then focus. My original code was almost exactly the same as the OP's. The important difference here is switching to use `Path.parent`. My implementation is for handling `Enter` for paragraph and `Enter+Shift` for `<br>` (that branch is under construction).

```
if (event.key === 'Enter' && editor.selection?.anchor?.path) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!event.shiftKey) {
    const anchorAndFocus = {
      offset: 0,
      path: [Path.parent(editor.selection.anchor.path)[0] + 1, 0],
    };
    const selection = { anchor: anchorAndFocus, focus: anchorAndFocus } as Location;
    Transforms.insertNodes(editor, { type: 'paragraph', children: [{ text: '' }] });
    Transforms.select(editor, selection);
  } // else want a break tag...
}
```

A week later of SlateJS work I found there's a flag `select` for `insertNodes` options, so you could consolidate the last two lines above to something like:

```
Transforms.insertNodes(
  editor, 
  { type: 'paragraph', children: [{ text: '' }] },
  { at: selection, select: true }
);
```